# Is is possible using equals and hashcode to avoid 1st empty or null object?

Tags: java, list, set

generally I do have a loop over a List where I first ignore specific objects (with null/empty attributes) and then I am putting them into a Set (to ignore duplicates), but I do wonder if there is an option to achieve both by using just .equals and .hashCode, especially when the 1st object is a "bad" one (null or empty), because either way the 1st object in a Set is always there.

Many thanks for better ideas.

```
List<QR> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add( new QR( 2, null, null ) );
list.add( new QR( 14, "", "" ) );
list.add( new QR( 5, "q", "r" ) );          // 1. good
list.add( new QR( 6, "q2", "r2" ) );        // 2. good
list.add( new QR( 7, "q", "r" ) );    
...

LinkedHashSet<QR> set = new LinkedHashSet<>( list );

System.out.println( set.toString() );
[null - null - null]


public class QR {
String qw;
String rst;
constructors, getters, setters

// My actual equals & hashCode never prevents 1st "bad" - null or empty object:
@Override
public boolean equals( Object o ) {
  if ( getClass() != o.getClass() ) return false;       // prevent casting excetion
  if ( this == o ) return true;                         // equal objects

  // ignore nulls and empties
  if ( qw == null || rst == null || qw.length() == 0 || rst.length() == 0 ) return true;

  QR qa = (QR) o;
  if ( qa.qw == null || qa.rst == null || qa.qw.length() == 0 || qa.rst.length() == 0 ) return true;

  // ignore equal qws or rsts (can't have multiple qw with the same rst and vice versa)
  if( qw.equals( qa.qw ) || rst.equals( qa.rst ) ) return true;

  return false;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Even if it was possible, this would be a really bad idea: it would make these methods do things they weren't designed to do. It would be hard to understand the code for anyone supporting it, and who knows what kinds of bugs might happen if someone made an innocent call to your equals method in another place.

Comment: It seems that you consider `QR` instances equal as soon as as any of `qw` / `rst` properties of either side of the comparison is null or empty (`QR(2, null, null)` is equal to any other `QR`) which does not sound correct.  Probably you should be checking if _both_ fields are null or empty, then instances could be equal.

Comment: Maybe if there will be one day another build-in methods, like isValid, filter, etc.. that will be a better way..

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using Lombok's `@Data and @AllArgsConstructor` first of all to make your code clean, hashcode and equals ready for use. Later you can achieve it using Java8's stream:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class QR {
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private int id;
    private String qw;
    private String rst;
}
```

and filter your data:

```
List<QR> yourClearList = list.stream()
            .filter(qr -> !Strings.isNullOrEmpty(qr.qw) && !Strings.isNullOrEmpty(qr.rst))
            .distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```